# Error in pom.xml overview in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java

There is a error in pom.xml overview showing:

> Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for org.apache.maven.plugins:mav.

I have tried to reinstall the maven again,
and it ends with the same error again and again. How can i fix this.

Comment: Hopefully one of these answers will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815639/cannot-read-lifecycle-mapping-metadata-for-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmav

Comment: @OhGodEverythingIsBroken Thank you it really worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:mav](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815639/cannot-read-lifecycle-mapping-metadata-for-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmav)