# pom.xml error in maven

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to import a maven project into eclipse,But getting the following error message -

> Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:maven-plugin:2.7:runtime
>   Cause: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

Please suggest the best way to resolve the same.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815639/cannot-read-lifecycle-mapping-metadata-for-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmav