# pom.xml error while creating a maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am a beginner in developing with spring framework

I'm trying to create a webapp with spring MVC with a login form.

The problem is that when i create a new maven project eclipse show me an error in pom.xml which is so weird.
could you help me  please .

```
ERROR: Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:maven-plugin:2.12.4:runtime Cause: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
```

[error of pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWKOa.png)

Comment: please attache error staktrace or error message

Comment: ERROR: Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:maven-plugin:2.12.4:runtime Cause: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

Comment: i m thinking to uninstall eclipse and re-install it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815639/cannot-read-lifecycle-mapping-metadata-for-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmav

Comment: thnx but could you help me to update maven like the solution said ? i didn t  understand how to update it

Comment: Yeah sure can you just post ur pom.xml file

Comment: i post it not on  comment but on answer because it s too long

Answer (score 1):

It is because of one or more jar files are corrupted, so it will be difficult to find out which jar is the problem.

So just **delete the `.m2` repository and restart the eclipse**.

If you are using window OS then location of `.m2` directory is **`C:\Users\{username}\.m2`**

It will work..!!

Comment: This one worked for me. I had to close eclipse to delete the .m2 repository though.

Answer (score 0):

```
**this is my code of pom.xml** 

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringMvcHibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMvcHibernate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMvcHibernate Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javax servlet api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- hibernate dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mysql connector dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4j dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: share a complete pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

See this is complete simple pom.xml of sample project which is correct and perfect working.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.irfan.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleSpringMaven</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SampleSpringMaven Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>SampleSpringMaven</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>my-tomcat</server>
                <path>/SampleSpringMaven</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

see if this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Removed the directory containing the different versions of the
  maven-war-plugin
- After this Start the build with mvn install -U
  to update all the plugins the error will go.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in parent tag then changing the Spring boot version worked for me. Earlier the version was 2.5.4 I changed it to 2.4.10.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -3):

I was changed parent version and its working fine

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247918/edit) your question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @MebinJoe this isn't a question, and the person who wrote the answer isn't OP.